# Microservice has high CPU Usage

Tags: java, multithreading, kubernetes, project-reactor

There are around 60 Microservices hosted in Kubernetes in my company. Two of them have the problem of high CPU usage after some time. The CPU of the pod jumps up to 100% (the pod got allocated with one CPU of a newer AMD EPYC Generation) and then keeps on working at this rate. This problem appears randomly somewhere between the application start and us noticing and restarting/deleting the pod in the Kuberentes dashboard.

The microservices all run with Spring-Boot 2.7.8 and using undertow instead of tomcat. As HTTP Library we're using Retrofit2 2.9.0 and OkHttp3 3.14.9. We're using Project Reactor.

The Thread Dump has one potentially abnormal entry:

```
"getProductVariants-260" #354 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=678915664.69ms elapsed=687202.16s tid=0x00007f63d800a800 nid=0x170 runnable  [0x00007f643ccec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:787)
        - locked <0x00000000f4132990> (a okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteException)
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:315)
        at java.lang.Exception.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Exception.java:102)
        at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/RuntimeException.java:96)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteException.<init>(RouteException.java:31)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:96)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at de.md.services.microframework.http.RetryInterceptor.intercept(RetryInterceptor.java:22)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at de.md.services.microframework.http.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:98)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at de.md.services.microframework.http.HeaderInterceptor.intercept(HeaderInterceptor.java:32)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at de.md.services.microframework.http.RetrofitClient.lambda$buildOkHttpClient$0(RetrofitClient.java:166)
        at de.md.services.microframework.http.RetrofitClient$$Lambda$1044/0x0000000100959c40.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
        at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.ExecuteSinkConsumer.accept(ExecuteSinkConsumer.java:39)
        at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.reactor.ExecuteSinkConsumer.accept(ExecuteSinkConsumer.java:24)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe(FluxCreate.java:95)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(FluxSubscribeOn.java:194)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.17/FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.17/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.17/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.17/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)
```

This thread does not look like it is running and this was always the case when I captured the dump. I also noticed that this thread stays, while other threads tasked with similar HTTP calls die after some time. This has been around for almost as long as the microservice runs. The thread seems to live as the stacktrace changes sometimes.

The Method getProductVariants looks like this:

```
public Mono<ProductVariantList> getProductVariants(String productVariantIds, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        ProductConnector productConnector = retrofitClient.buildRetrofitClientReactorDefault(
                connectorConfig.getProductService(), connectorConfig.getDefaultTimeout(), getProductVariantsScheduler,
                httpServletRequest).create(ProductConnector.class);
        return productConnector.getProductVariants(productVariantIds, connectorConfig.getSlapToken()) //
                .doOnNext(res -> ThirdPartyUtils.checkRetrofitResponse(res, LOGGER, "ProductService"))
                .flatMap(MonoHelper::toResponseContentMono) //
                .doOnError(error -> LOGGER.error("getProductVariants ist auf einen Fehler gelaufen.", error));
    }
```

The default timeout is 10 seconds. The scheduler is from Project Reactor and has a thread cap of 40 and a que cap of 100000. The connector just executes a ReST request and aquires less than 150kb of data from another microservice not related to this problem.

The requests to this microservice are about 10 to 20 per minute and they are received by two instances of this microservice.

The memory consumption of the service is normal and so is the memory dump. Does anyone have an idea how to look further into this matter?